# Is it possible to map NCPDP d.0 to XML using Smooks?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, edi, smooks

I have a file containing NCPDP data (NCPDP d.0) and I want to map it to my Java classes using Smooks. In the past I have used Smooks for EDI X12, but I am having trouble using it for NCPDP.

**What I've tried:**
I have defined the delimiters (RS,FS,GS), but Smooks is not detecting any of the segments/segment Code from the given string of NCPDP format, also in the given NCDP format the file control codes are non printable. They can only be seen in Notepad++ .

Comment: i have defined the delimiters (RS,FS,GS) but smooks is not detecting any of the segments/segment Code from the given string of ncdp format, also in the given NCDP format the file control codes are non printable they can only be seen in Notepad ++

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your comment into the question. Comments are temporary here, so it's best to get as much relevant information in the question itself. I noticed that you refer to NCPDP first, but consistently refer to NCPD in the comments. I _think_ you meant NCPDP in both cases, but didn't want to change that without verifying. If it should be "NCPDP" instead of "NCDP", please [edit] your question accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: You may also want to explain a little more about your Java classes, and how the mapping is supposed to work. The better you explain the problem, the better people will be able to help.

Comment: Thank you @S.L.Barth for fixing my question, I am new here it will take some time for me to get to the standards and as for my problem i have solved it.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to see you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it, was using the wrong version of XML because of which control codes were not working for SMOOKS.

Comment: Just sharing had similar issues, need to specify something like <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the top of your xml docs as well.